# QTCreator g++.exe: fatal error: no input files (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compiler-errors, qt-creator

An error occurs during the build:

code *.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

QT = widgets

TARGET = MYPROJECT
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
           mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

code mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

As a compliant is installed: `C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe`

The assembly is made in Windows 10 64 bit.

In time the assembly i get so error:

> g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated.
>   09:38:38: The process "C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe" ended with code 1.
>   Error in assembling / installing the MYPROJECT project (set: MYPROJECT_DESCTOP)
>   During the "Build" stage

I tried include full path to files in .pro file, but it isn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all your code files in the current working directory, otherwise you'll have to include their path in the compile command.

Comment: Yes, it helped. I added path to files ".C:\Qt\Qt5.6.3\5.6.3\Src\qtbase\include\QtWidgets\QMainWindow`".